# name of algebraic structure generalizing closure and interior

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a name for an algebraic structure equipped with an involution and two additional unary functions that "act like" the interior and closure of a set?

I'm after something a little bit like an [$i$-lattice](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1958-087-02/S0002-9947-1958-0095135-X/S0002-9947-1958-0095135-X.pdf) / [DeMorgan algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan_algebra) but additionally with something that "feels like" $\square$ and $\lozenge$ from modal logic.

Suppose we take the sets of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and consider the operations $\cup(\cdot, \cdot)\;,\; \cap(\cdot, \cdot)\;,\; \cdot^\complement\;,\; \mathrm{int}(\cdot)\;,\; \overline{(\cdot)} $ , so union, intersection, complement, interior, and closure.

$\cup$ and $\cap$ distribute over each other and are duals with respect to $\cdot^\complement$ and $x^\complement{^\complement} = x$ .

Interior are closure are also dual and each is idempotent.

$$ \mathrm{int}(x^\complement)^\complement = \overline{x} \tag{1} $$

$$ \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{int}(x)) = \mathrm{int}(x) \tag{2} $$

And the union of the closures is the closure of the (finite) union(s).

$$ \overline{x} \cup \overline{y} = \overline{x \cup y} \tag{3} $$

Here's an example of a finite structure satisfying the rules. The domain of our structure is $\{\text{-1}, 0, 1\}$

$$ x \cap y \stackrel{df}{=} \min(x, y) \tag{4} $$
$$ x \cup y \stackrel{df}{=} \max(x, y) \tag{5} $$
$$ x ^\complement \stackrel{df}{=} -x \tag{6} $$
$$ \mathrm{int}(\text{-1}) \stackrel{df}{=} \text{-1} \\
   \mathrm{int}(0) \stackrel{df}{=} 0 \\
   \mathrm{int}(1) \stackrel{df}{=} 0 \tag{7} $$
$$ \overline{(\text{-1})} \stackrel{df}{=} 0 \\
   \overline{0} \stackrel{df}{=} 0 \\
   \overline{1} \stackrel{df}{=} 1 \tag{8} $$

Note that it isn't possible to swap the definitions in (7) and (8) because of (3) ... which guarantees that union and closure "move things in a similar direction".

Comment: I think this falls into the category of [Boolean algebras with operators](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-0697-1_6#citeas)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Isn't it amazing that one could own that book for *$389?!!*

Comment: @rschwieb and now only $549, even more a steal! :)